# An error popping up while trying to create a new source file, or trying to open an old code

Tags: c++, dev-c++

While trying to crate a new file, or open an old code in Dev c++ an error pops up. the error message is :

> 'clBtn' is not a valid integer value.

I've had this problem for a couple of days now. I have three options, to send anonymous bug report, to continue or to terminate. I don't think I deleted something that lead to this issue. Also I have never had this issue before, any advice would be helpful.

Comment: I'd uninstall and reinstall the IDE.

Comment: I've faced a lot of trouble with DevC++, so generally I either use CodeBlocks now or the ultimate weapon VSCode ;)